# Tastypie login returns HttpResonse 500

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I'm trying to get a Tastypie login system to work, however when I send a json request with the user data, the server responds with Http 500. I have looked through all of my code and tried to debug the issue but nothing I try is working.

I've looked around and can't find anything to help me.

Does anyone know how I can go about fixing this issue or if there is something I should be doing that I am not.

Thanks.

## api.py

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):
    raw_password = fields.CharField(attribute=None, readonly=True, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email']
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'post' ]
        resource_name = 'user'

    def prepend_urls(self):
        return [
            url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/login%s$" %
                (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash()),
                self.wrap_view("login"), name="api_login"),
            url(r'^(?P<resource_name>%s)/logout%s$' %
                (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash()),
                self.wrap_view("logout"), name="api_logout"),
        ]

    def login(self, request, **kwargs):
        self.method_check(request, allowed=['post'])

        data = self.deserialize(request, request.raw_post_data, format=request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE', 'application/json'))

        username = data.get('username', '')
        password = data.get('password', '')

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return self.create_response(request, {
                    'success': True
                })
            else:
                return self.create_response(request, {
                    'success': False,
                    'reason': 'disabled',
                }, HttpUnauthorized)
        else:
            return self.create_response(request, {
                'success': False,
                'reason': 'incorrect',
            }, HttpUnauthorized)

    def logout(self, request, **kwargs):
        self.method_check(request, allowed=['get'])
        if request.user and request.user.authenticated():
            logout(request)
            return self.request.create_response(request, {'success': True})
        else:
            return self.request.create_response(request, {'success': False}, HttpUnauthorized)
```

## request.py

```
import json
import requests

data = {"username" : "test", "password" : "password"}
headers = {"content-type": "application/json"}
url = "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/user/login/"

response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)

print response
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with `request.raw_post_data` it's deprecated and should be changed to `request.body` hope this helps anyone else having issues.

Comment: I would but it doesn't let me for 2 days. Once I am able to, I will.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it's worked for me!

**api.py**

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):
    raw_password = fields.CharField(attribute=None, readonly=True, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'post' ]
        resource_name = 'user'
        authentication = Authentication()
        authorization = Authorization()
        serializer = Serializer(formats=['json'])


    def prepend_urls(self):
        return [
            url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/login%s$" %
                (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash()),
                self.wrap_view("login"), name="api_login"),
            url(r'^(?P<resource_name>%s)/logout%s$' %
                (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash()),
                self.wrap_view("logout"), name="api_logout"),
        ]

    def login(self, request, **kwargs):
        self.method_check(request, allowed=['post'])
        data = self.deserialize(request, request.body, format=request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE', 'application/json'))
        username = data.get('username', '')
        password = data.get('password', '')


        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        print user
        if user:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return self.create_response(request, {
                    'success': True
                })
            else:
                return self.create_response(request, {
                    'success': False,
                    'reason': 'disabled',
                }, HttpUnauthorized)
        else:
            return self.create_response(request, {
                'success': False,
                'reason': 'incorrect',
            }, HttpUnauthorized)


    def logout(self, request, **kwargs):
        """
        Attempt to log a user out, and return success status.
        """
        self.method_check(request, allowed=['get'])

        # Run tastypie's BasicAuthentication
        self.is_authenticated(request)

        if request.user and request.user.is_authenticated():
            logout(request)
            return self.create_response(request, { 'success': True })
        else:
            return self.create_response(request, { 'success': False, 'error_message': 'You are not authenticated, %s' % request.user.is_authenticated() })
```

**request.py**

```
import json
import requests

data = {"username" : "test", "password" : "password"}
headers = {"content-type": "application/json"}
url = "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/user/login/"

response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
print response
```

**In terminal**

```
In [2]: import requests

In [3]: import json

In [4]: data = {"username" : "test", "password" : "password"}

In [5]: headers = {"content-type": "application/json"}

In [6]: url= "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/user/login/"

In [7]: response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)

In [8]: response
Out[8]: <Response [200]>
```